# spyder4 beta5 reports missing dependencies which are already installed

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, xdgutils

I installed spyder4 in ubuntu using `pip install --pre -U spyder`. When I run it I get a pop-up window which states:

```
You have missing dependencies!
xdg >=0.26: None (NOK)
```

I'm sure xdg-utils is installed. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to run

```
pip install -U pyxdg
```

to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I can't run this command. I get the error: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'pyxdg'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: I guess you installed our beta with `sudo`, right? If that's the case, that's a horrible practice because you're messing with your system Python by doing that, and that can have disastrous consequences. My recommendation is to use a virtualenv instead.

Comment: I did ! I used 'sudo'. Didn't know it was bad practice. I can't uninstall is either. I get the same error. What can i do now to remove it?

Comment: You need to go to `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/` (or whatever you're Python version is) and remove what you find there by hand (although I don't know if you installed other Python packages with `sudo` besides Spyder and you need them).

Comment: I installed other packs using 'sudo'. Is installing packages with 'sudo' a bad practice in general? or just for beta projects?

Comment: Installing Python packages with sudo is a really bad practice in general because you're mixing your Linux distro curated list of packages with newer, possibly untested versions of other packages. If you installed more packages, you should really remove them and use virtualenvs instead.

Comment: Got everything working. Thanks so much. Unfortunately, spyder4 does not work in my computer yet. The mouse and keyboard do not work in every frame of the IDE. Look forward to use version 1.